# How do I parse "4.20833333333333E-03" to Double?

Tags: .net, type-conversion

I have a text file which contains seconds as denoted like this:

```
"4.20833333333333E-03"
```

My current approach to convert it to Double results in:

```
420833333333.333

Dim sNumber As String = "4.20833333333333E-03"
Dim d As Double = Double.Parse(sNumber)
```

How would I parse this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
Dim d As Double = Double.Parse(sNumber, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```